# Como impedir o redirecionamento de um link e mesmo assim mudar a url?

Tags: php, jquery, html5

Eu tenho um menu lateral com vários links, estou utilizando ajax para que quando alguém clicar em um dos links o conteúdo central da pagina seja modificado. Como faria essa operação ??

Atualmente estou usando esse código:

```
<script>
    $('li:contains(Registro Local)').click(function(event){
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('li:contains(Registro Local)').addClass('active');
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.content_wrap').load('link-da-pagina');

  });

</script>
```

Isso faz com que a pagina seja carregada mas não altera a url.

Comment: Você já leu algo sobre <section> do html? Creio que isso ajudaria vc

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazer o [pushState(stateObject, title, url)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)

```
<script>
    $('li:contains(Registro Local)').click(function(event){
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('li:contains(Registro Local)').addClass('active');
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.content_wrap').load('link-da-pagina');

    history.pushState("", "", '/sua-nova-url');
  });
</script>
```

O primeiro parametro é um objeto que fica associado a nova pagina/estado/
O segundo é o titulo da pagina, que é ignorado
O terceiro é a nova URL